# File pattern analysis: tool to count frequency of string of hex bytes

Tags: linux, data-analysis

I'm looking for a tool to help me analyze a binary file. There are tools which provide you with rank, the character that appears most of the time, (such as the character that appeared the most times is *c* with frequency *f*). But I want one which is able to do that not just for one character but for a string of hex bytes, (rather than just a string of chars).

For example, looking at the paragraph above, the string of hex bytes *'7468'*, (*"th"*), appeared 11 times.

It would be a plus if the tool is available for Linux.

Comment: Practically all your text is about *characters*, yet you ask for a *binary* file. Please [edit] and remove the ambiguity. Also: what is the limit to the set of characters - any logical one or just the number of characters. What are you trying to accomplish? Price?

Comment: What's up with "characters". Of course, a [binary file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file) has ASCII [character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_%28computing%29), maybe unprintable but are still called characters. And as for "text". binary file can contain readable text.

Comment: See also: [How to find recurring patterns on a hexdump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406560/how-to-find-recurring-patterns-on-a-hexdump)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple python code implementation. The code reads as a binary [rb] the file [file_path], then for the given set of characters [user_set], it counts how many each set occurred in the file and makes a dictionary [stat] with 'character set in hexadecimal' as key, and 'count of that character set' as value. Finally, prints character set in hex with their corresponding count, ordered by count.

```
import operator
file_path = 'example.bin'
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()

length = content.__len__()
user_set = 3

stat = {}

for i in range(length - user_set):
    select = content[i:i + user_set]
    count = 0
    for j in range(length - user_set):
        if select == content[j:j + user_set]:
            count += 1
            i += user_set - 1
    if count>1:               # if count=1, then its not included
        stat[select] = count


sorted_stat = sorted(stat.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

for x in range(1,len(sorted_stat)):
    print(sorted_stat[x][0].hex()," :appeared -->",sorted_stat[x][1],"  times")
```

an example result

```
f7d483  :appeared --> 5   times
0191ed  :appeared --> 2   times
019075  :appeared --> 2   times
```

Comment: Please clarify which of the following hex strings would, (and would not), be counted amount the *5* appearances of *"f7d483"* if they were converted to binary:  1) *"f7df83"*  2) *"df83f7"*  3) *"f78383"* 4) *"f783"* 5) *"f700d40183"*.

Comment: @agc only the first one will be counted as f7d483. the code is looking for a three character string, that appears more than once. I probably did not understand your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Strings or characters?

1. If it's strings...

   Using `strings` to show the Top 10 strings in the kernel:

   ```
   sudo strings /vmlinuz | 
        tr -s '[-[:space:]_]' '\n' | 
        sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
   ```

   Output:

   ```
       521 SPRQ
       443 3021
       418 rq
       328 OHDLBJFNAIEMCKG
       323 g`dbf
       278 f
       270 z
       260 g
       260 /
       254 L
   ```

   To narrow this down, just add a `grep` in there, with whatever set
   is of interest, (let's say it was *"aeiouy"*):

   ```
   sudo strings /vmlinuz | 
        tr -s '[-[:space:]_]' '\n' | 
        grep -i '[aeiouy]' | 
        sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   328 OHDLBJFNAIEMCKG
   215 U
   211 o
   209 O
   206 u
   197 y
   195 i
   193 Y
   193 E
   175 I
   ```
2. If it's characters...

   ```
   sudo hexdump -v  -e '/1 "%.2x"'  -e '/1 " _%_u\_\n"' /vmlinuz | 
        sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
   ```

   Output shows Top 10 chars:

   ```
    204518 00 _nul_
     44349 ff _ff_
     38958 fe _fe_
     38507 7f _del_
     37624 bf _bf_
     37101 fd _fd_
     37066 fc _fc_
     36655 3f _?_
     36560 df _df_
     36509 fb _fb_
   ```

   To narrow this down, just add a `grep` in there, with whatever set
   is of interest, (let's say it was *"aeiouy"*):

   ```
   sudo hexdump -v  -e '/1 "%.2x"'  -e '/1 " _%_u\_\n"' /vmlinuz | 
        grep -i '_[aeiouy]_'  | 
        sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head
   ```

   Output:

   ```
     34369 6f _o_
     33810 4f _O_
     33809 79 _y_
     32162 61 _a_
     31528 45 _E_
     31453 49 _I_
     30951 59 _Y_
     30358 75 _u_
     30204 65 _e_
     30190 69 _i_
   ```

   See also: [*"How to gather byte occurrence statistics in binary
   file?"*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157092/165517)

Comment: Two years later the above code proves to be fragile and probably locale dependent.  The first method with strings now only outputs single bytes -- but the code will output strings if the `tr -s '[-[:space:]_]' '\n' | ` is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

I also don't understand  what you want exactly, but here is something off the top of my head:

One such command line tool to extract characters from binary files is  `strings`.

With `perl` you can analyse the output.

This command will count the number of vowels in strings extracted from a linux kernel binary:

`sudo strings /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-55-generic | perl -000 -nlE "my \$s = tr/[aeiou]//; say \$s;" -`

`33627`

If you want to count the number of fields (words) containing the string "Canonical" or "Douglas" in the Ubuntu Linux kernel, try this:

`sudo strings /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-55-generic | perl -alne 'map { /Canonical|Douglas/i && $t++ } @F; END { print $t }'`

`8`

Comment: Links to documentation on the web for strings and perl would make this so much more useful an answer.

Comment: If you don't understand the question, you can ask in the comment. And your answer is not what I was looking for if you read my question. But I appreciate the effort. P.S. I have already found a way to solve my problem.

Comment: @avendesta If you have solved your problem, you should post that solution as an answer. It is perfectly fine for you to do so and encouraged. You can even accept your own answer.